# Why do I go to the top of the page when I open my fixed navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed side navigation menu that has a height of 100%. When you click the hamburger in the corner its width gets set to 15%-100% depending on your window's size. And when you click the x its width is set to 0. The percentage is set relative to the body. This seemed to be working great until I added content so that I could scroll. When you scroll down and then open/close the side nav it brings you back to the top of the page.

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript so it is possible there is a problem in there. I searched Google and StackOverflow but I didn't find anything. It's possible I might not be searching for the right problem. I tried changing all of the percentages to vh and vw and that changed nothing. I also don't believe it is a browser problem (I use Chrome) because I tried it in Microsoft Edge as well and that produced the same results.

```
<body onresize="WindowResize()">
<!--side-menu-->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="open-Slide">
      <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
        <span id="hamburger" class="icon-menu"></span> /*an Icon font I have downloaded*/
      </a>
    </span>
    <div id="side-menu">
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
<!--end of side-menu-->
```

```
    //side-menu script
    var sideMenuWidth;
    var sideMenuIsActive = true;
    window.onload = function() {
      if (window.innerWidth > 1143) {
        sideMenuWidth = '15%';
      }else{
        sideMenuWidth = '100%';
      }
    }
    function openSlideMenu () {
      document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = sideMenuWidth;
        sideMenuIsActive = true;
    }
    function windowResize() {
      if (window.innerWidth > 1143) {
        sideMenuWidth = '15%';
        if (sideMenuIsActive == true) {
          document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = sideMenuWidth;
        }
      }else{
        sideMenuWidth = '100%';
        if (sideMenuIsActive == true) {
        document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = sideMenuWidth;
        }
      }
    }
    function closeSlideMenu() {
      document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
      sideMenuIsActive = false;
    }
  //end of side-menu script
```

```
#side-menu {
  width:15%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#hamburger {
  display: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  color: black;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove href attribute from <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">

Comment: instead of using `a` element, use `button` element and call `openSideMenu()` function when this button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need interactive element, but don't need `href` attribute use `<button>` element instead and apply needed CSS for this element. This is better option from accessibility concern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default behaviour for link with attr href="#" or remove href
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp